# Why does EKS Service NodePort can't switch traffic?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I found a problem regarding the EKS Service NodePort that cannot switch traffic.

I deployed two pods below for game-service on EKS Cluster qa-api-cluster in namespace qa.

This game-service uses a selector in the label app and version to switch traffic to different pods.

ex:

```
 Pod                        game-service selector
qa-game-blue-xxxx      app=game,version=qa-v0.0.132
qa-game-green-xxxxx    app=game,version=qa-v0.0.133

// game-service in svc
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
selector:
    app: game
    version: qa-v0.0.133
type: NodePort     // Cannot switch traffic, while LoadBalancer is fine
```

However, if you update the version in game-service with type NodePort to switch traffic, this will take more than 30 mins or even longer take effect.

What is worst, qa-game-green and qa-game-blue will receive traffic randomly.

While game-service with type LoadBalancer, this will take effect immediately and only one pod can receive the traffic.

Why does a service (game-service) with type NodePort cannot switch traffic but type LoadBalancer can?

Is this Kubernetes's spec or AWS's specific design?

Should I set it up as Load Balancer or are there any settings I can tweak for NodePort?

Answer (score 0):

After further testing, EKS has no problem switching traffic in service type NodePort or Load Balancer.

I found the cause of this problem was the idle connection timeout between ALB and the backend service pod. ( especially my application has activated the keep-alive feature without an idle timeout).

This made the old pod keep the old connection to ALB until ALB disconnects it at timeout while no traffic.

This is very hard to find it out and maybe useful for you to reference if having the same situations.